# Delete all duplicated rows in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame which has duplicate observations, how do I delete **all** the duplicated ones **based on the first column** (if their first data is the same, then delete these entries entirely)?

```
> a=c(1,4,5,5,6,6)
> b=c(2,5,7,4,4,2)
> c=c("a","b","c","a","b","c")
> test=data.frame(a,b,c)
> test
  a b c
1 1 2 a
2 4 5 b
3 5 7 c
4 5 4 a
5 6 4 b
6 6 2 c
```

I don't want to keep any of the duplicate rows so that my final output will be

```
  a b c
1 1 2 a
2 4 5 b
```

I've tried `unique` and `duplicate` function but they both keep the first duplicate rows (i.e., if there are 5 duplicate records then 4 of them will be deleted), like

```
  a b c
1 1 2 a
2 4 5 b
3 5 7 c
4 6 4 b
```

What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand why your final output should be that. I do not understand why you consider other rows as duplicated

Comment: How is `6 4 b` a duplicate? Why do you want to delete it

Comment: @Pop I mean duplicated ones based on the first column. The 3rd and 4th rows have the same 5 as their [,1], and the 5th and 6th rows have the same 6 as their [,1].

Comment: @Floo0 Because the next row `6 2 c` also starts with 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `table()` to get a frequency table of your column, then use the result to subset:

```
singletons <- names(which(table(test$a) == 1))
test[test$a %in% singletons, ]

  a b c
1 1 2 a
2 4 5 b
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`

```
require(dplyr)
test <- test %>% group_by(a) %>% filter(n()==1)
test

  a b c
1 1 2 a
2 4 5 b
```

Comment: Thanks, it also works! Actually I know nothing about `dplyr` before. Andrie answered first so I accepted his answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You first search for the first column values of the duplicated rows:

```
val <- test[duplicated(test[,1]),1]
[1] 5 6
```

Then you search for the rows in which these values can be found

```
rows <- test[,1] %in% test[duplicated(test[,1]),1]
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Then you select all rows except these:

```
test[! rows,]
  a b c
1 1 2 a
2 4 5 b
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange request, but if you want to remove all rows where there is a duplicate in any column while ignoring the other columns:

```
test[!duplicated(test$a) & ! duplicated(test$b) & ! duplicated(test$c),]
  a b c
1 1 2 a
2 4 5 b
3 5 7 c
```

But I don't see how '5 7 c' is a duplicate in your example.

Comment: Because the next row `5 4 a` also starts with 5. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Easy one step removal of duplicates:

```
my_df <- my_df[-which(duplicated(my_df)), ]
```